# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode [sqlserver - hibernate 4.3.11 - spring 3.2.8 - Wildfly 18]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get this error on my code when I try to execute a stored procedure (Microsoft SqlServer):

"org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode () Lorg / hibernate / FlushMode;"

The server on which my web application is installed is WildFly 18.
Below is a screenshot of the maven dependencies:

[Screenshot maven dipendencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDEqC.png)

Can anyone help me to understand which is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.